# Adding a row to a table with data from report?

Tags: ms-access, automation, vba, report

Right now, I've got a database that allows a user to create a basic report based on a query from a table using a parameter. Pretty straightforward. What I want to do now is to use VBA to add a record into a separate table every time a report is created. Each report has the information from the query PLUS some new information (concatenated IDs, dates, etc.). The new table ("Summary") would include some of that new information plus a few sources from the original query. It would be sort of a dynamic log of reports created.

Is there any way to use VBA to combine data from the two sources (data displayed on report from original query and native report data) into one record on a table?

Here's the code I've got so far.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub Log_Report()

'System definitions
Dim dbs As DAO.database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rep As [Report_Custom MARS Report]

'Original report sources
Dim Text267 As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim Company_Name As String
Dim ReportID As String

'Summary table destination
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Date_Created As Date
Dim Source As String
Dim Title As String
Dim report_ID As String
Dim Attachment As Attachment

End Sub
```

I'm probably way off, so if I have to start over, I'm fine with that. I'm no expert in VBA by any means, so it's been a lot of trial and error so far.

I can clarify if needed.

Comment: If you have a query, why not take the data from the query using a recordset?

Comment: if you have a query, why not store the query used to generate the report?

Answer (score 0):

If the record set for your report is a single row, it would be relatively easy to use the on load event to read the fields and assign them to variables. All of the calculations have been done by the time your Report_Load event fires and you could then use them as inputs to a function which writes the values to your summary table.

```
'Code to placed in a public function
'strVar = text267 'is ReportID = report_ID ? 
'Unfortunately I have no experience with attachments, sorry

function writeReportSummary(intID as Integer, dtmDate_Created as Date, strSource as String, strTitle as string, strReportID as string, strVar as string, strTableName as string, strCompanyName as string, attAttachment as attachment) AS boolean

Dim strSQL as string
On error goto Err_Handler

strSQL = "INSERT INTO summary( ID, Date_Created, Source, Title, report_ID, Text267, tableName, Company_Name, ReportID) SELECT """ & intID & """ , """ & dtmDate & """;" 'etc
CurrentDb.execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Debug.print CurrentDB.recordsAffected & ": Record(s) Inserted at " & now()
writeReportSummary = True
Exit function

Err_Handler:
debug.print err.number
debug.print err.description
writeReportSummary = false
end function

'Code to be placed in Report_load'
Sub Report_Load

if Not(writeReportSummary(intID, dtmDate, etc)) then debug.print "Failed to write report to summary table"

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I tried using your code and I'm getting an error when put it in the OnLoad event. It's saying that the "Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return variant or object." The error is occurring at 'writeReportSummary = True'